# Error: Input type "color" isn't supported by md-input-container

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to add an input for color selection using angular material 2 as follows:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input  mdInput type="color">
    <md-icon mdSuffix>edit</md-icon>
  </md-input-container>
```

and I got this error  :Error: Input type "color" isn't supported by md-input-container.
is there any alternative that would fit in a form

Answer (score 1):

Material inputs do NOT support the 'color' type. Use a simple input instead:

```
<input type="color">
```

You can still style it as you wish and mimic a material input by adding an icon etc.